# Assign variable values and remove JButtons once clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have written a working script for battleships which works for any number of ships/grids rows/grid columns to be assigned at the beggining. I have attached the working code below. I now want to allow the player to choose an easy or hard option by clicking on respective buttons at the beggining of the game, this should then: 
assign values to the ships(in code written as hits), grid rows & grid columns variables
remove the easy and hard buttons from the JFrame
and then let the game continue accordingly

Could anyone suggest how to do this?

```
package battleshipswithinterface;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class BattleShipsWithInterface extends JFrame
{
    private static final String TITLE="Battleships";
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400; //Window width
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;  //Window height

    public static final int gridRowSize =6;
    public static final int gridColumnSize =5;
    public static final int numberOfButtons =gridRowSize*gridColumnSize;

    public int[] hits=new int[4];//location of ship
    public int hitSize=hits.length;
    public int shotHit;

    public int pressedColumn;
    public int pressedRow;
    public int hitRow;
    public int hitColumn;

    private Container content;
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private JButton initButton;
    private JLabel commentary;
    private JButton exitButton;

    //build a constructor
    public BattleShipsWithInterface()
    { 
        setTitle(TITLE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        content=getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        content.setLayout(new GridLayout((gridRowSize+1),gridColumnSize));
        buttons = new JButton[numberOfButtons]; //can we make Jbuttons 2D array?
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++)
        {
            buttons[i]=new JButton(" ");//(""+(i+1));
            buttons[i].putClientProperty("point",i);
            buttons[i].addActionListener((ActionListener) new ButtonsListener());
            content.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        initButton=new JButton("START AGAIN");
        initButton.addActionListener(new InitButtonListener());
        content.add(initButton);

        exitButton=new JButton("EXIT");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());
        content.add(exitButton);

        commentary=new JLabel("Play Battleships!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        commentary.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);//could be 'setVerticalAlignment'??
        commentary.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        commentary.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN,10));
        content.add(commentary);
        init();

    }
    public void init()
    {   
         Random random = new Random();
        for (int hit=0; hit<hitSize; hit++)
        {
            hits[hit]=random.nextInt(numberOfButtons);
            for (int check=0; check<hit; check++)
            {
                if (hits[hit]==hits[check])
                {
                    do 
                    {
                        hits[hit]=random.nextInt(numberOfButtons);
                    }
                    while (hits[hit]==hits[check]);    
                }
            }
        }   

        shotHit=0;

        setVisible(true); //display window  
        commentary.setText("Play Battleships!");

        for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].setText(" ");//(""+(i+1)); for alphabet!
        }  
    } 

    private class ButtonsListener implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JButton pressed=(JButton)(e.getSource());
            String text=pressed.getText();
            int index=((Integer) pressed.getClientProperty("point"))+1;

            int Remainder=index%gridColumnSize;
            if (Remainder==0)
            {
                pressedRow=index/gridColumnSize;
                pressedColumn=gridColumnSize;
            }
            else
            {
                pressedRow=((index-Remainder)/gridColumnSize)+1;
                pressedColumn=Remainder;
            }

            int row=0;
            int column=0;

            if (shotHit!=hitSize) ///consider taking this out - it may already be implied
            {
                if (text == "X")
                { 
                    commentary.setText("Already clicked!");
                    buttons[index-1].setText("X");    
                }
                else if (text=="*")
                {
                    commentary.setText("Already clicked!");
                    buttons[index-1].setText("*");
                }     
                else if (success(pressed))
                { 
                    shotHit++;
                    buttons[index-1].setText("*");
                    if (shotHit==hitSize)
                    {
                        commentary.setText("You Win!!!"); 
                    }
                }     
                else
                {
                    pressed.setText("X");
                    commentary.setText(" ");//could be better written if buttons indexed as 2D array

                    for (int k=0; k<hitSize; k++)
                    {

                        int hitRemainder=((hits[k]+1)%gridColumnSize);
                        if (hitRemainder==0)
                        {
                            hitRow=(hits[k]+1)/gridColumnSize;
                            hitColumn=gridColumnSize;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hitRow=(((hits[k]+1)-hitRemainder)/gridColumnSize)+1;
                            hitColumn=hitRemainder;
                        }
                        if (hitRow==pressedRow)
                        {
                            row++;
                        }
                        if (hitColumn==pressedColumn)
                        {
                            column++;
                        }
                        commentary.setText(column + " Ships in column " + pressedColumn +", "+ row + " ships in row " + pressedRow);

                    }
                }      
            }
        }
    }    

    public boolean success(JButton pressed)
    {
        int score=0;
        for (int q=0; q<hitSize; q++) 
        {
            if (pressed==buttons[hits[q]])
            {
                score++;
            }

        }
        if (score>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class InitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            init();
        }
    }

    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    // create instance of GridWindow in main method
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BattleShipsWithInterface gui=new BattleShipsWithInterface();
    }

}
```

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use,

```
buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
```

This will make your button frozen, and won't let users click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use diferent actionListener for each button, makes it easier:

```
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
                            buttons[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                    //rest of your code
            }
    });
```